# How to fetch data from a list of objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner in Objective C.

I would like to know how we can fetch data from a list of objects[objects of a particular class] by using for loop.

Comment: What type of "list of objects"? Your question is very vague.

Comment: What is `FlightFlight_MBOList`? does it adopt NSFastEnumeration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loop. Here is the sample code to accomplish the problem

```
for(int itemIndex = 0;itemIndex < yourCollectionCount; itemIndex++){


    id myObject = yourCollection objectAtIndex:itemIndex]; //replace id  with your Collection Individual Item dataType

}
```

or

If you know the index of item, then use

```
id myObject = yourCollection objectAtIndex:knownIndex]; //replace id  with your Collection Individual Item dataType
```

Comment: Since we don't understand the question, you should at least imagine that the list adopts the NSFastEnumeration protocol. In that case, which is the normal case, you would suggest fast enumeration. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html

Comment: But really, asking for clarification is the right thing to do here, before you answer. Without it, the question will be closed and you get no points nor prestige.